# Thumbnail of Blogger post in Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook-like, thumbnails, blogger

I posted the following in my blogger page to add individual Facebook "likes" to each post -

```
<script>
document.write(&#39;&lt;iframe src=&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<data:post.url/>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=380&amp;action=like&amp;font=trebuchet+ms&amp;colorscheme=light&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowTransparency=&quot;true&quot; style=&quot;border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:25px&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&#39;);
</script>
```

After clicking "like" in specific post, such story will also appear on the timeline of the one who clicked "like". However, the thumbnail is not working.

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v369/q_quincyluk/fb_like_bug.jpg

How can my pictures in individual posts be shown as thumbnails?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing the `og:image` meta tag on the post which tells Facebook which image to use

Run your page through the debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to see which tags you're missing and/or what Facebook is detecting for each URL.

Comment: Please try entering http://lateshowwithquincysuneo.blogspot.com/ at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

What does that mean?

Comment: It means you haven't provided any value for og:url, og:title or og:image